# Animate LazyColumn items content size in Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn, android-jetpack-compose-lazy-column, jetpack-compose-animation

I have a LazyColumn with items that have subsections, that appear and disappear on click.

I want to animate the items content size change: when I click on an item, I want to reveal its subsection (or hide it), and I want other items to animate accordingly.

I tried adding the animateContentSize modifier to the items. It works well, but there are problems when I scroll the LazyColumn (since items are converted, some items change size even though they weren't clicked, and sometimes the expanded items don't fully show).

What's the best way to animate items content size change in composables such as a LazyColumn